# How to pickle a subclass instance if super (from fixed library) rejects it?

Tags: python, oop, pickle, subclass, dill

I'm subclassing `logging.Logger` and although I'm implementing `__getstate__` very safely, I get an error by the superclass saying you cannot pickle this. How to get around this?

Minimal reporducible code:

```
import logging
class MyLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __getstate__(self): return {}

import pickle
pickle.dumps(MyLogger('name'))
```

Result:

```
PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [12], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 pickle.dumps(MyLogger('name'))

File C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py:1739, in Logger.__reduce__(self)
   1737 if getLogger(self.name) is not self:
   1738     import pickle
-> 1739     raise pickle.PicklingError('logger cannot be pickled')
   1740 return getLogger, (self.name,)

PicklingError: logger cannot be pickled
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by overriding `__reduce__` from superclass. I'm not sure though why `__getstate__` & `__setstate__` where not sufficient in this instance. They usually are.

```
    def __reduce__(self): return self.__class__, tuple(self.specs.values())
```